# String stream joining: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Tags: java-8

Using java8 to concatenate an object certain field value with a "_". The last line in the code throws an "`stream has already been operated upon or closed`".

```
Stream<Field> fields = ...
Stream<String> exclusions = ...
Stream<String> stringStream = fields.filter(f -> exclusions.anyMatch(e -> e.equals(f.getName())))
        .map(f -> {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = null;
            try {
                value = f.get(obj);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return value;
        })
        .filter(v -> v != null)
        .map(Object::toString);
String suffix = stringStream.collect(Collectors.joining("_"));
```

EDIT: I have tried this with:

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.stream().filter(item -> item != null).map(item -> {
    String value = null;
    return value;
}).filter(item -> item != null).map(item -> {
    String value = null;
    return value;
}).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

And there is no such exception.

Comment: You are trying to reuse `exclusions` stream  for every element of `fields`.  A stream cannot be reused.  Put your exclusions into a `Set` and filter by `f -> ! exclusionsSet.contains(f.getName())`

Comment: @Misha why `exclusions` stream is reused? I think it is used once which is in the first filter.

Comment: @Misha @Eugene OK. I understand. In another usage I have `filter(f -> !Arrays.stream(exclusions).anyMatch(e -> e.equals(f.getName())))` so the same array is turned into a stream for every item and therefore that is ok.

Comment: @Tiina I made that an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many times is the first `filter` called? More then once right? The exclusions that you use in the first call to filter is consumed via anyMatch; thus the second time you try to use it - you get the exception.

The way to solve it, would be to stream on every single filter operation:

```
filter(f -> sourceOfExclusions.stream().anyMatch...
```